# Tag type as string variable in selenium

Tags: css, selenium

How to pass tag type as a string variable in selenium?

suppose I am having given example:

```
By.cssSelector: li[__idx='0']
```

for given example I tried below part

```
webElement.findElement( By.cssSelector( "'" + tag + "'['" + property + "'='" + indexNumber + "']" ) )
```

where tag is li and __idx is property.
I am getting error as " Could not locate element with locator ". but if I tried as below then its working correctly.

```
 webElement.getElement().findElement( By.cssSelector( "li[__idx='" + indexNumber + "']" ) )
```

Is there any syntactical mistake am doing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
webElement.find( "" + tag + "[" + property + "='" + indexNumber + "']" );
```

This is the correct way to solve the issue.